# Increase in Solr response time during replication time (Solr 4.2)

Tags: performance, solr

Below are our master and slave (14 slaves) configurations

### Master

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" 
        class="MyCustomizedReplicationHandler" >
    <lst name="master">
        <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
        <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>      
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

### Slave

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" 
        class="MyCustomizedReplicationHandler" >
    <lst name="slave">
        <str name="masterUrl">http://${masterHostName}/solr-master-4.2.0/${solr.core.name}</str>
        <str name="pollInterval">04:00:00</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

We have scheduled a batch to run every day and the response time during the very first replication is high as there will not be any changes in the  following replications of the same day.

### Solr Query

```
(AC_SEARCH:(belfast*) AND (TYPE:(ARP) OR HAS_AIRPORTS:(true)))
```

I gave direct Solr query here but we use Solr Client to communicate with Solr from application.

The same kind of query's response time is different during replication time and non-replication time.

Please help me to fix this, anything do I need to change in the configuration to achieve this.

Comment: Can you clarify what the batch does (batch load of data or batch read?) also which version of Solr you use? Also how many documents are in the index and how many documents are you loading / reading in the batch?

Comment: @kellyfj
1. batch is to load the data,
2. Solr version - 4.2.0,
3. We are having 7 cores each has around 1300000 documents in it,
4. batch will update the existing data and rarely it will add new data

Comment: Due to the heavy indexing load I would suggest monitoring CPU and Disk I/O - is CPU maxed out during indexing (if so you might need to scale up) - if there are long queues or delays writing to disk you might need to look into speeding up the Disk access.

Comment: FWIW Solr 5 introduced replication throttling https://sematext.com/blog/solr-5-replication-throttling/ - so your batch load process would be slower but it might help reduce system load to handle queries faster.

Comment: I am not seeing any high usage on CPU, IO etc.,

Comment: Do you see any problem if I migrate Solr 4.2 to Solr 5?

Comment: I don't see any problem - but unless you are seeing high CPU, disk or network I/O spikes during batch loading I'm not sure the upgrade will help.

Comment: is there any other configurations you know that will help us?

Comment: A common thing people do is set autoSoftCommit to a small number (1 or 2 seconds). If you can try increasing that it might help.

Comment: Where can I find this configuration?

Comment: solrconfig.xml - see for example https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

Comment: @kellyfj, When I try to migrate the solr from 4.2 to 8.0 which is the latest one, I am getting error in the below method (ReplicationHandler).

`NamedList statistics = getStatistics();
Long version = (Long) statistics.get("indexVersion");
Long generation = (Long) statistics.get("generation");`

seems that the getStatistics() method got removed after Solr 6.6